# Self-inductance of a finite solenoid

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, inductance

[image: Electricity and Magnetism by B Ghosh]

Where did the $l$ in the denominator come from? I am talking about the $l$ in muNI/2l[...]?
I can't match LHS and RHS.

Comment: Looks like a typo. The dimensions are not consistent.

Comment: Typo, as the middle formula should have $\ell$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a typo. Usually it is $N_0$ which number of turns in a unit length. After everything is calculated it is usually expanded out to N/l. Where N is the number of turns in the solenoid and l is the length of the solenoid.